# Android API Difference Report Download

Tags: android

I am developing a tool in which I need to use the "Android API diff reports". Can I download them in any format?

I think it will be tedious to automate reading the given diff reports in the website. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

When you download the SDK you have the option to download the docs as well. The diff reports are part of the documentation. Best option is to see how it's laid out in the sdk docs and attempt to read the files as needed.

If you wanted to go a little crazy I suppose it would be possible to process the actual android.jar travel though it using reflection. You could setup a documentation format then and compare however you wished.